# Custom Leaflet Renderer for GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to render GeoJSON differently than provided by Leaflet by default. Unfortunately changing the `style()` function will not suffice as I need greater control over the vector graphics being created.

What is the idiomatic way of doing this? I reckon I can reuse lots of parts of the default SVG renderer found in `src/layers/vector/SVG.js`. I would however like to only replace it for one GeoJSON layer / one FeatureGroup. As none of these inherit from `Path`, this does not seem possible.

I tried extending the SVG class in a very basic way:

```
import {SVG} from 'leaflet/src/layer/vector/SVG'

export default class CustomSVG extends SVG {
  _updatePoly (layer, closed) {
    console.log('Custom renderer in action')
    super._updatePoly(layer, closed)
  }
}
```

and then set it as the renderer while initializing Leaflet, but this fails with a `TypeError: max2 is undefined` (it is an unhandled promise rejection which stems from me using `react-leaflet`).

What is it I'm missing?

Comment: What kind of "greater control over the vector graphics" do you need?

Answer (score 1):

I read the documentation again and I seem to have missed [this bit about the GeoJSON options](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#geojson-style):

> `style`: A Function defining the [Path options](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#path-option) for styling GeoJSON lines and polygons, called internally when data is added. The default value is to not override any defaults:
>
> ```
> function (geoJsonFeature) {
>   return {}
> }
> ```

The path options on the other hand take a renderer, which I can use to override the rendering of this particular GeoJSON layer only. Hope this helps anybody else!